# JSON - populate a form from table links

Tags: jquery, json, hyperlink, html-table, dynatable

I'm close to the edge here, so any help would be greatly appreciated. I attempting to make each row of data a clickable link and that link would be the id in the JSON data. The idea behind this would be that once the user clicks a link the code would populate a form on another page of my app.

I've just started to learn Jquery after years of using Actionscript and it isn't going to well at the moment.

**JSON DATA**

```
var data = [
{ 
    "code" : "SF700JR",
    "color" : "Orange",
    "description" : "RAL 2000",
    "finish" : "Smooth",
    "gloss" : "Satin",
    "id" : "uk1",
    "series" : "D1036"
  },
    {
    "code" : "YA602GF",
    "color" : "White",
    "description" : "RAL 9016",
    "finish" : "Smooth",
    "gloss" : "Gloss",
    "id" : "uk2",
    "series" : "D2525 SD"
  },
  { "code" : "YA604GF",
    "color" : "White",
    "description" : "RAL 9018",
    "finish" : "Smooth",
    "gloss" : "Gloss",
    "id" : "uk3",
    "series" : "D2525 SD"
  }
]
```

**JQUERY**

```
  var dynatable = $('#my-final-table').dynatable({
    features: {
      paginate: false,
      recordCount: false,
      sorting: false,
      search: false
    },
    dataset: {
      records: data
    }
  }).data('dynatable');

  $(data).each(function(index, value) {
    var row_content = $('<a href="#">' + value.id + '</a>');
    value.id = row_content;
    console.log(row_content);
    $('#my-final-table tr').append('<a href="#">'+value.color+'</a>').data(value);

    $('#my-final-table tr a').on('click', function(){
      console.log("click");
    });
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-grid-solo"><p></p>
    <div class="ui-block-a">
    <table id="my-final-table" class="product-table" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <th class="table-heads">Description</th>
            <th class="table-heads">Code</th>
            <th class="table-heads">Series</th>
            <th class="table-heads">Color</th>
            <th class="table-heads">Gloss</th>
            <th class="table-heads">Finish</th>
            <th class="table-heads">ID</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is wrong: ``$('#my-final-table').dynatable`` it is ``$('#my-final-table').datatable``

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention i'm using the dynatable plugin to convert the json data to a table.